# Product Topology on the Unit Square

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a problem that asks me to compare the product topology on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with various other topologies on it. My question is, what do they mean by product topology; what topology is each factor of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ endowed with? The problem does not specify this. I figured $[0,1]$ has the topology inherited as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the standard topology, but I would like confirmation of this.

Comment: If it doesn't say anything more, then it must be that topology you guessed...

Comment: If it's not specified, it's probably safe to assume the standard topology. It's _standard_, after all.